# bootstrap 4 element hiding classes aren't working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, hide

I have a Bootstrap  container that holds two side-by-side Divs. I am trying to hide the image in the left div when the viewport is resized to the col-sm size, but the Bootstrap classes aren't hiding the div, no matter how small I make the viewport. I have JQuery code controlling the scrolling for both inner div's.

What could be causing the issue?

Here is my container:

```
    <div id="showsynopsis" class="container-fluid parallax">
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-md-6 d-none d-md-block">
             <div id="showgraphic" style="background: url('images/poppins.jpg') 5% 100% no-repeat;"></div>
          </div>
          <div id="info" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <h2>Mary Poppins</h2>;
             <h3 class="josefin">Aug 9-11, 2018</h3>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
    #showgraphic{
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width:50%;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 758px){
    #showgraphic{
        display:none;
    }
    }
```

Comment: I pasted your code on jsfiddle and the left div gets hidden on small viewport: https://jsfiddle.net/pinguinosod/aq9Laaew/132737/

Comment: Huh. Well, the background image I have on the div is actually populated by PHP. Would that make a difference?

Comment: I figured it out. I discovered that some of my other css was broken, too. I had left off the meta tag for the viewport and device info.